# How to move files with a specified extension to a new folder in Python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to move files within a folder to another folder whilst only moving files with the extensions `.bmp`.

I am using the `shutil.move()` method and it works when I don't specify file types but once I do it stops working. I have tried to debug it but cant figure out why my code isn't working. I dont get any tracebacks, nothing happens.

```
 import time
 import os
 import shutil
 from datetime import datetime

 today = datetime.now()

 src = "."
 dst = ('C:\Python\Image Compressor\File Saving\Archive\BDB040803_St14_' + 
 today.strftime('%d_%m_%Y'))
 files = os.listdir(src)
 for file in src:
     if file.endswith(".bmp"):
          shutil.move(os.path.join(src,file), os.path.join(dst,file))
```

Comment: remember about proper indentation within if statement where you are checking file extension

Comment: @pkolawa my if statement is indented properly in my code but for some reason its showing up like that when I post it. I edited the post now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have finally solved my problem. I will post my code here for a reference for anyone else who runs into this problem. @siloob thank you for your input, you were correct with your correction but I still had tracebacks after this so I had a few more changes to make.

I needed my bmp files to transfer and not my .py files so I added an if statement with a continue to skip over any files with .py. This solved my problem and only transferred the bmp files.

```
 import time
 import os
 import shutil
 from datetime import datetime

 today = datetime.now()

 src = "."
 dst = ('C:\Python\Image Compressor\File Saving\Archive\BDB040803_St14_' + 
 today.strftime('%d_%m_%Y'))
 files = os.listdir(src)
 for file in files:
     if file.endswith(".py"):
         continue
     else:
         shutil.move(os.path.join(src,file), os.path.join(dst,file))
```

Comment: But if you keep your ```if file.endswith(".bmp"):``` your .py file isn't moved ? Because here if you have another file than .py (.bmp or all others) they will be move to

Answer (score 2):

Replace `src` by `files` in line:

```
 for file in src:
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in an alternative approach (yours isn't bad, this isn't meant as criticism).

You could use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date

src = Path()
dst = Path(
    r"C:\Python\Image Compressor\FileSaving\Archive\BDB040803_St14_"
    + date.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
)
for file in src.glob("*.bmp"):
    file.replace(dst / file.name)
```

[`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) allows you to fetch path/file-names that match patterns. The pattern structures aren't as powerful as regex, but can still be pretty helpful. You could also use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/glob.html) module directly.

[`.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) takes over `shutil.move`'s job.